# Switch current sense resistor: series or parallel?

Tags: current-measurement

I am building a device that measures current in various ranges. For this I want to switch in different current sense resistors. To do this I see two ways: the resistors in series or the resistors in parallel.

Series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fm3w9v.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Parallel:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJePUi.png)</sup>

They produce slightly different values, but that doesn't really matter all that much, because I have to calibrate it for the actual values anyways.

But I am wondering if there are any inherent advantages or disadvantages of one method over the other for current sense purposes.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice that ;-) I'll make an edit

Comment: It's just for future reference. Your circuit is very simple.

Comment: Fairly simple I think, you just need to find the equivalent resistances and compare them each other.

Comment: Read up on Kelvin sensing. Yes, from THE Lord Kelvin.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf Kelvin sensing for a 1k shunt resistor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shunt resistors are *big enough* to neglect trace resistances, switch contact resistances, etc. Therefore, there is no real need to use Kelvin sensing.

The shunt resistors are *small enough* to neglect isolation resistances, etc.

So, there is no significant difference between placing the switches in parallel or in series.

Comment: Sounds good! Does anything change given that the cmos switches i want to use have about 100 ohm on resistance?

Comment: @Jens The \$R_{DS(on)}\$ of analogue switches depends on supply voltage, signal voltage (or: input voltage) and temperature. 100\$ \Omega\$ is only 10% of 1k\$ \Omega\$, so 10% deviation on \$R_{DS(on)}\$ gives a 1% measurement error. Since they are also cheaply available, I would have picked an analogue switch with a lower ON resistance.